# Tables in RMarkdown

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown, knitr

I am new to RMarkdown and R. I have created some data.frames that I want to include in a RMarkdown PDF. I know I can just use the data.frame itself, however, it is FAR from pretty. What are some easy packages or methods to convert data.frames into excellent looking tables in RMarkdown? Where do you suggest I start!?

Comment: Consider kable with kableExtra to start with https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-7.html

Comment: As @SusanSwitzer already mentioned, you can create nice tables with [kableExtra](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf).